# Migrate Eclipse 3 SWT app to JavaFX

Tags: javafx, swt, eclipse-rcp

I need to perform a migration from SWT to JavaFX.
I've found some tutorials, but the all operate with e4 apps. Is it possible to do my task from Eclipse 3.x application?

What's the easiest way to do it, with minimum coding?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The Eclipse 3.x APIs assume SWT so this is not really possible.

A simple example is the:

```java
public void createPartControl(Composite parent)
```

method in `IWorkbenchPart` used to create editors and views, here `Composite` is an SWT class.

Comment: Is there some way, for example, to migrate 1st to E4 project, and then add JavaFX features?

Comment: e4 does not have any equivalent of a lot of the 3.x APIs. So, for example, if you are using anything from `org.eclipse.ui.xxxx` plugins you can't convert to e4 easily. Note that you can run JavaFX from within an SWT app https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I'd like to add there is a swtfx implementation who allows to move from e4-swt to e4-fx gradually - see http://www.kware.net/?p=64